# "large" image files not getting saved using paperclip in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, paperclip, passenger

Uploading and resizing images of any size works flawlessly on my desktop running development and productions modes. On my server running an apache/passenger setup any image file over 1 MB returns one of two errors

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/243.jpg20120504-2852-ryheox[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/243.jpg20120504-2852-ryheox[0]' -resize "400x400" '/tmp/24320120504-2852-l69yg'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Error: There was an error processing the thumbnail for 243>
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/243.jpg20120504-2852-ryheox[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/243.jpg20120504-2852-ryheox[0]' -resize "200x200" '/tmp/24320120504-2852-g957f'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Error: There was an error processing the thumbnail for 243>
```

or

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/046.jpg20120504-946-1w1106[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/046.jpg20120504-946-1w1106 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/046.jpg20120504-946-1w1106[0]'
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /tmp/046.jpg20120504-946-1w1106 is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

Smaller files have no issues.

I have about 3 GB free disk space and when trying to upload files my free memory never drops below 60MB and there is 300MB of swap space.

Is there some special setting I am missing? The environment production file is whatever was generated when the rails app was created.

EDIT:

I can upload video files in excess of 50MB and just store them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change client_max_body_size in nginx.conf to whatever size you want

edit: try adding

```
LimitRequestBody 15000000
```

to your apache conf file

Comment: Thanks, I am using apache, but I am doubting it is an apache issue since I can upload video files that are over 50 MB in size.